# How to check Regex for character / (escape slash) and ^ Using Shell Scripting Linux

Tags: regex, linux, shell, scripting

I want to check if there is specific character inside a line using shell scripting for linux. So far the code using regex (regular expression)  can recognize some character, but there is problem when check char '^' and '/' (i just check this two, and maybe '\' also.

Here is the codde

```
VALID='0-9a-zA-Z $%&@.#<>-'
while read line
do  
        if [[ ! $line =~ [^$VALID] ]]; then
        echo ""         
    else                    
        echo "File not okay. Contain Invalid Character"
        exit 1                      
    fi
done < $1
```

if run the program by reading file, let say the line contain

```
<CurrencyTarget>IDR</CurrencyTarget>
```

the program will run and then stopped when reach '/'.
but if you remove '/' (or '^' if exist) and replace it with (let say) '&'

```
<CurrencyTarget>IDR<&CurrencyTarget>
```

the program will display "File not okay. Contain Invalid Character".

how to fix the behaviour of / and ^ character?
i already try using /\ or //\ (googling and i got this) but still error.

nb : i know the error caused because if using ^ then argument ^$VALID will become ^^ also if using / then argument ^$VALID will become ^/ , but i dont know how to fix it properly.

Any Help really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition is the problem:

```
if [[ ! $line =~ [^$VALID] ]]; then
                 ^^^^^^^^^
```

You can use it as:

```
valid='^[0-9a-zA-Z $%&@.#<>-]+$'
line='abc-123'

[[ $line =~ $valid ]] && echo "matched" || echo "no match"
```

Comment: how about to check for special character such as Ç or å or any special character like shown in http://tools.oratory.com/altcodes.html ? because your code not work for the special character.

Comment: Try my updated example in answer. `Ç or å` will not match `^[0-9a-zA-Z $%&@.#<>-]+$` hence you will get `no match`

Comment: Thanks. it works. but i wonder why change the position of number make the output become different>?

Comment: Actually regex variable `$valid` should be unquoted after `=~` operator. So `[[ $line =~ $valid ]]` will work but `[[ $line =~ "$valid" ]]` won't.